# Percentage based max-height on transformed elements

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a fixed position pop up window that I transform to center in the page.

This window is capable of increasing/decreasing in size as elements are added to it and I want to limit its growth to 75% of the window.

At the moment I define it's max-height using ems because, as I understand it, when an element is transformed it is taken out of flow and so no longer has a parent element to base percentages on.

Is there some pure css way I can make the max-height of this element based on the total window size even though I use transform?

Edit - add code example:

```css
.fade-in-container {
    text-align: left;
    display: table;
    max-height: 55em;
    width: 40em;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    position: fixed;
    height: 20em;
    z-index: 12;
    padding: 2em;
    background: #F1F1F1;
    border-radius: 1%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <footer></footer>
    <div class='fade-in-container'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have an example to help us visualize? Also, have you tried using `vh` as your dimension unit?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
#your-div {
    max-height: 75vh;
}
```

**Viewport Percentage Lengths**

https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/#article-header-id-12

Comment: Sure, edited my question with some of the html and all css on the main fade in window

Comment: Your example seems to work well with `max-height: 75vh;`. What isn't working for you?

Comment: I see, it looks like my issue was not with the parent div but the max-height I define in some of it's expanding children. I've been able to get something working by adjusting their values using vh. Not particularly clean but it'll work.

Thanks for the help!